# Django ImportError: No module named although it is already in my python search path

Tags: django, python-2.7, webfaction

I am solving this for quite a long time already.

I print like this.

```
python2.7 -c "import sys; print sys.path"
```

And I saw my module directly there.

> ['', '/home/khantthulinn/lib/python2.7/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg',
>   '/home/khantthulinn/lib/python2.7',
>   '/home/khantthulinn/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib64/python27.zip',
>   '/usr/lib64/python2.7', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2',
>   '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old',
>   '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload',
>   '/home/khantthulinn/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
>   '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages',
>   '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PIL',
>   '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/geos',
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

But I always get this error. How shall I solve?

> Unhandled exception in thread started by  Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/khantthulinn/webapps/mmspeaker/lib/python2.7/Django-1.8.14-py2.7.egg/django/utils/autoreload.py",
>   line 229, in wrapper
>       fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/khantthulinn/webapps/mmspeaker/lib/python2.7/Django-1.8.14-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py",
>   line 107, in inner_run
>       autoreload.raise_last_exception()   File "/home/khantthulinn/webapps/mmspeaker/lib/python2.7/Django-1.8.14-py2.7.egg/django/utils/autoreload.py",
>   line 252, in raise_last_exception
>       six.reraise(*_exception)   File "/home/khantthulinn/webapps/mmspeaker/lib/python2.7/Django-1.8.14-py2.7.egg/django/utils/autoreload.py",
>   line 229, in wrapper
>       fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/khantthulinn/webapps/mmspeaker/lib/python2.7/Django-1.8.14-py2.7.egg/django/**init**.py",
>   line 18, in setup
>       apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)   File "/home/khantthulinn/webapps/mmspeaker/lib/python2.7/Django-1.8.14-py2.7.egg/django/apps/registry.py",
>   line 85, in populate
>       app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)   File "/home/khantthulinn/webapps/mmspeaker/lib/python2.7/Django-1.8.14-py2.7.egg/django/apps/config.py",
>   line 86, in create
>       module = import_module(entry)   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 37, in
>   import_module
>       **import**(name) ImportError: No module named push_notifications

Comment: It is inside '/home/khantthulinn/lib/python2.7'. I am hosting on webfaction and I don't use virtual environment though.

Comment: are other packages within that same directory importing without issue?

Comment: very strange. all are okay like restframework. Only push_notifications is not okay.

Comment: have you double checked to ensure that `push_notifications.py` in fact exists?

Comment: Amm..what is push_notification.py ? I saw folder for push_notifications though. https://postimg.org/image/p3uaj9skr/

Comment: There should be a directory called "push_notifications" or filed called push_notifications.py. Your import error is pointing to it being unable to locate that module. From your screenshot it's hard to tell if it successfully installed or now. It does appear, based on your import path, that it should be able to find it. Have you ensured that you've installed it 'pip install django-push-notifications`